# How to scale object with more vertex to other to fit perfectly?

Tags: modeling

im coming here for help. I need scale this object with more vertex to the other but need to match exactly, how i can do that?
If i scaling and press ctrl to snapping is not work:/
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: y don't you copy its dimensions

Answer (score 0):

It should work.. e.g. set your snap as follows, to use the 'Active Element' to snap from, and 'Vertex' to snap to, ensuring the snap is set to affect 'Scale'..

[image]

Select all the vertices on the smaller circle, taking care to have a vertex (say one on the X axis?) matching one of the outer circle's vertices active at the end of your selection, and scale it out to snap to its match on the outside.